# Change datetimepicker default language [datetimepicker]

Tags: jquery, date, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using DateTimePicker in my project. I want to change the language. How can I run it using the https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-tr.js plugin in this example. Thanks in advance ..

```
 $('#appoimentDate').datetimepicker({
       format: "dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii",
       language: "tr"
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Put it directly in your datetimepicker options.

```
$('#appoimentDate').datetimepicker({
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy hh:ii",
    closeText: "kapat",
    prevText: "&#x3C;geri",
    nextText: "ileri&#x3e",
    currentText: "bugün",
    monthNames: [ "Ocak","Şubat","Mart","Nisan","Mayıs","Haziran","Temmuz","Ağustos","Eylül","Ekim","Kasım","Aralık" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "Oca","Şub","Mar","Nis","May","Haz","Tem","Ağu","Eyl","Eki","Kas","Ara" ],
    dayNames: [ "Pazar","Pazartesi","Salı","Çarşamba","Perşembe","Cuma","Cumartesi" ],
    dayNamesShort: [ "Pz","Pt","Sa","Ça","Pe","Cu","Ct" ],
    dayNamesMin: [ "Pz","Pt","Sa","Ça","Pe","Cu","Ct" ],
    weekHeader: "Hf",
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: ""
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading `datepicker-tr.js` after `jquery-ui.js` in your HTML, it should already be using `tr` language.

Eg.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker-tr.js"></script>
```

Checkout the [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/U9HyJDuUppbsPMsVp92j?p=preview) I created.